# Concurrent VPN connections using the same user?

Tags: windows-7, router, vpn

This is a simple question from an humble programmer who was asked to setup users on a third-party-configured VPN.

I created a user using PPTP on a Cisco RV180W router. Then I configured 3 laptops running Windows 7 to connect to the VPN using the same user.

Now, I get connection problems at "random" from users connecting to the VPN, is it because only one user can connect with the same credential at a time? In other word, is this the issue and I should create a user for every computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single user can establish multiple PPTP VPN as long as you have enough IP address in your address pool.